# Strings in a function

Tags: ida

I have two simple questions in IDAPro:

1. How can I find string references in one function only (not the whole program) ?
2. How can I breakpoint on each string reference in IDAPro ? It is easy to do in OllyDbg but I don't know how to do it in IDAPro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to learn IDAPython if you want to automate things in IDA.
For your specific task, here is an example:

```
 # I didn't check this code, use carefully, beware of errors

import idc
import idaapi
import idautils

def set_breakpoints_on_refs(ea):
    list_of_referencing_functions = ["All"]
    print "In setting bp ..."
    for ref in idautils.DataRefsTo(ea):
        func_name = idaapi.get_func_name(ref)
        if not func_name is None and not func_name in list_of_referencing_functions:
            list_of_referencing_functions.append(func_name)
    print "refrlist done", list_of_referencing_functions
    width = 0
    for r in list_of_referencing_functions:
       if len(r) > width:
           width = len(r)

    ch = idaapi.Choose(list_of_referencing_functions, "Choose a function", 1 )
    ch.width = width
    print "Chooser created"
    res = ch.choose()
    if res > 0:
        print "selected ...", 
        chosen = ch.list[res -1]
        print chosen
        set_at_all = False
        if chosen == "All":
            set_at_all = True

        for ref in idautils.DataRefsTo(ea):
            if set_at_all:
                idc.AddBpt(ref)
                continue
            func_name = idaapi.get_func_name(ref)
            if func_name == chosen:
                idc.AddBpt(ref)


def set_breakpoints_on_refs_to_screen_ea():
    print "Started"
    set_breakpoints_on_refs(idc.ScreenEA())

idaapi.add_hotkey("Alt-Y", set_breakpoints_on_refs_to_screen_ea)
```

Running this code from execute script window will register hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> that will do the following:

- will get the current screen ea (let's assume that you placed the cursor on desired string),
- create a list of functions that containing references to this ea
- will ask you to choose one of them or all
- and will set breakpoints on corresponding  references (all or in chosen function)

Answer (score 0):

For the refs, you can sort the list of xrefs and look only at a specific group:

[image]

For the string ref thing, you should put a hardware breakpoint on access on the string, like this:

[image]

Comment: I know that method but I want to have automated way right click inside a function and select show string reference in that function and break point on them directly...the reason is that I do this operations a lot